# Ошибка при записи метаданных в файл с помощью eyeD3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я создал скрипт, который будет загружать всю музыку с ВК на мой компьютер.
Все получилось, но вот настали некоторые проблемы с eyeD3.

Тот, кто знает, как это решается, ответьте пожалуйста

Код:

```
from eyed3 import id3
import requests


def load_mp3(file_n):
    tag = id3.Tag()
    tag.parse(file_n)
    return tag


file_name = "test song - test.mp3"
path = "/home/USER/path/to/file/"

url = "https://cs1-74v4.vkuseraudio.net/p10/151f34219b8183.mp3?extra" \
      "=4njs8U_XdSnBWGryb0LQhgJjbyi3riqXk9Rb7VaC00STG9gv_hCURT3oSvd63H1fSS0pgRVz_xfqEgX19qvtRbOJ205Lkg9cGl" \
      "-UuGydHyCdwfaqdFqUpbEqV021sUjh2PxcAYkiDX05GnP9_09IEvgXzVc "

with open(path + file_name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)

    file = load_mp3(path + file_name)
    file.title = "Name"
    file.artist = "Author"
    file.track_num = "228"

    file.save()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/homus/PycharmProjects/vk_bot/TEST5.py", line 26, in <module>
    file.save()
  File "/home/homus/PycharmProjects/vk_bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eyed3/id3/tag.py", line 897, in save
    raise NotImplementedError("Unable to write ID3 v2.2")
NotImplementedError: Unable to write ID3 v2.2
```

если что, я сижу на kubuntu.

Comment: код который дал выше не из скрипта, но он похож и выдает точно такую же ошибку что и основной скрипт

Comment: В этом проекте столкнулись с такой же проблемой и их решением было заменить eyed3 на Mutagen: https://github.com/tooxie/shiva-server/issues/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на другом сайте ответили. 
решение:

```
file.save(version=(2, 4, 0))
```

Comment: Решение оказалось намного проще, чем предполагалось :)